# Unlink of file failed despite no other process having a lock on the file

Tags: windows, git

I'm trying to switch branch. Before that I want to commit 2 files I changed, and discard(reset) changes to 1 file in my current branch.

I attempt to reset this 1 file, using this command:

```
git checkout origin/feature/FeatureABC/  c:\source\abc.xml
```

It responds with a blank line, and after I hit ENTER a few times, I see the message below:

*Unlink of file 'source/abc.xml' failed. Should I try again? (y/n):*

After I respond with `n`, it displays the following error:

*error: unable to unlink old 'source/abc.xml': Invalid argument*

Every answer for a similar problem in SOF says that this file is being locked by some other process. I checked with ProcessExplorer and couldn't see any other process holding this file.

I tried 3 GIT clients (PowerShell, GITExtensions, TortoiseGIT) all with elevated permissions. None of that helped. I tried them one at a time, with all other programs closed. Still no success.

My git version is 2.11.0.windows.3 on Windows 2012 64bit

All I want is to reset this file; what is it that I can try to just do that?

Comment: Not that it's really a solution, but might have diagnostic value: have you tried manually deleting the file (`del c:\source\abc.xml`)?  Does it work, or show some specific error, or...?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Able to delete; from "Git CMD" and Explorer; not able to delete from PoshGit

Comment: You could try using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to watch which process accesses the file in question while the operation. There can be some temporary access which does not last for long enought to be found with ProcessExplorer.